# How to put name attribute to md-select in Angular js Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I used Angular js material in myapp so native select box is replace with     but i want to  write some validation  and Other script based on  form input name attribute instead of ng-model.For exapmle

```
<form name="myForm">
<p>Name:
<input  ng-model="myName" required>
<span ng-show="myForm.myName.$touched && myForm.myName.$invalid">The name is required.</span>
</p>

</form>
```

So i need to put name attribute to

Reference Link:https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect

Is any solution is available for this? Actually i want  this "myForm.myName.$touched"   in the case of md-select in my Application

Answer (score 0):

From **HTML5**; **input** element has **form** attribute, which can add any input element out of form to it.
like:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" id="form1">
   First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" form="form1">
```

I think this maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just include `name` attribute to `md-select` and it should works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqwbjO

Hope it helps!